# Insufficient memory opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, pca, face-recognition

I am beginner to OpenCV and C++.
I am trying to write PCA code for face recognition using 3 different faces. For this, each image(of size d=mxn) is reshaped to a column vector of d elements.

```
typedef vector<Mat> Row;
Row img1v(36000,img1);
Row img2v(36000,img2);
Row img3v(36000,img3);
```

I calculate the vector of mean of the images as follows:

```
Row meanImg;
 for(int i=0;i<img1v.size();++i)
{
  meanImg.push_back((img1v[i]+img2v[i]+img3v[i])/3);
}
cout<<meanImg.size()<<endl;
```

Here I get an error:

> OpenCV Error: Insufficient memory (Failed to allocate 144004 bytes) in OutOfMemoryError

My image size is 180x200. I don't know what to do? Also how can I form a row vector in opencv using C++? (For calculating covariance I need to multiply difference vector with its traspose).

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? At which position does the error occur? What is the type of ``img1``?

Comment: I do not get the meanImg size.....Output terminal shows this error. img1 is cv::Mat

Answer (score 1):

I don't know OpenCV and its types. But your `typedef` looks suspicious.

My guess is that the error occurs while creating the `imgXv` instances of `Row`. For each call of `Row imgXv(36000,img1);` a vector is created that consists of 36000 instances of `Mat` that are all copies of the `imgX` instances. See constructor *2)* of `std::vector::vector` in [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector):

> `vector( size_type count, const T& value, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());` (2)
>
> 2) Constructs the container with count copies of elements with value value.

So you`re trying to keep **108003 images** in memory. Each of your images consists of 36000 pixels. If each pixel is represented by at least 1 byte, this would occupy a minimum of **3.6 GB** of memory.

From what I get of your approach you don't want that, but rather a `typedef vector<float> Row;` and `Row imgXv(36000);`

Comment: I'm not sure how to understand your _thanks_. Did the answer solve your problem? Anything remained unclear? As a @KeenLearner and presumably a beginner in SO you might be interested in this [FAQ link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and this [meta discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251288).

Comment: Instead of using typedef vector<Mat> Row, I used a matrix of size 36000x1.

Comment: ...which is a vector of a type depending on the type used by ``Mat``. But how to deal with it is not topic of this question.